# Create sepArate CSS files in next.js using webpack after production build

Tags: webpack, next.js, code-splitting

I need help in Next.js configuring the next.config.js file such that after production build the webpack/loaders some home create two separate css files and embed/link into index.html.

I'm using scss/sass for the project.

Consider two seperate scss named as:

1. *.paid.module.scss
2. *.free.module.scss

Some files line Home.paid.module.scss, Orders.paid.module.scss etc...

After production build i need all paid scss in paid/[hash].css and all free scss in free/[hash].css